# C# documentation update after method signature change

Tags: c#, documentation

In C# I use `///` for documenting methods. Is there any possible way how to update this documentation after method signature changes (without loosing information already entered)?

For example. I already have:

```
/// <summary>
/// Example method for my question.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userName">User name</param>
public void SomeMethod(string userName)
{
}
```

I would like to update method documentation after method changes to:

```
public void SomeMethod(string userName, int age)
{
}
```

Edit: I'm looking for some automated solution for this task.

Comment: You can manually edit the XML. In this case just add `/// <param name="age">Age</param>`

Comment: Beside from doing it manually you can use refactoring tools like Resharper. But it's not free. Maybe you find a free refactoring tool that also refactors XML comments. But renaming is supported by Visual Studio.

Comment: If you are a student then Resharper is free.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm going to do it with Resharper trial version. I've tried to find something free with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [GhostDoc](https://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx).  It's on the [visual studio marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeb.GhostDoc) too.

I've used the free version which will document methods for you (and update them).  Just place the cursor on the method definition and press `CTRL + SHIFT + D` (by default) to update method/class documentation.

Below would be the result after updating your example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Example method for my question.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userName">User name</param>
/// <param name="age">The age.</param>
public void SomeMethod(string userName, int age)
{
}
```